# Problem with chappg.sty when using glossaries-extra.sty

Tags: page-numbering, acronyms, glossaries-extra

The following code only includes abbreviations that typeset on page A-1. (I get the error "(6 entries accepted, 4 rejected)" when I build the list.) The document builds correctly if I remove the call to chappg.sty. I need to correct this problem.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}% Page numbers included.
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}% glossaries-extra.sty
\makeglossaries
\newabbreviation{irs}{IRS}{Internal Revenue Service}%%
\newabbreviation{us}{USA}{United States of America}%
\newabbreviation{ssn}{SSN}{Social Security Account Number}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printglossary
\chapter{Introduction}
\textbf{First use of four} \gls{irs}\\
\textbf{Second use of four} \gls{irs}.\\[0.5in]
\lipsum[2-8]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\textbf{Third use of four} \gls{irs}\\
\textbf{First use of four} \gls{us}\\
\textbf{Second use of four} gls{us}.\\[0.5in]
\lipsum[2-8]
\clearpage
\begin{appendix}
\chapter{An appendix}
\textbf{Fourth use of four} \gls{irs}\\
\textbf{Third use of four} \gls{us} \\
\textbf{First use of three} \gls{ssn}\\
\textbf{Second use of three} \gls{ssn}\\[0.5in]
\lipsum[2-8]\\
\textbf{Fourth use of four} \gls{us}\\
\textbf{Third use of three} \gls{ssn}\\[0.5in]
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the following solution from D.P. Story at AcroTeX in a personal communication.
"Just under the glossaries-extra package

```
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}% Page numbers included.
\GlsSetWriteIstHook{\write\glswrite{page_compositor "-"}} % dps
```

The problem was the page_compostor variable in the IST file that makeindex uses was set to 
page_compositor ".", for some reason."