# How to properly use chappg and glossaries together

Tags: hyperref, memoir, glossaries

I use `chappg` to give me page numbers of the form `2-1` for page 1 of chapter 2 for example.

`glossaries` compiles and everything seems to work but it fills the console with warnings of the type:

> Package glossaries Warning: Hyper target `1.1' can't be formed by prefixing location `1-1'. You need to modify the definition of \theHpage otherwise you will get the warning: "`name{page.1-1}' has been referenced but does not exist" on input line 20.

The (excellently detailed) [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (page 90) suggested adding `glsSetCompositor{-}` but this doesn't seem to change anything.

**Things tried (but that did not lead to a solution) :**

- This question suggested something similar to `glsSetCompositor`: [chappg with glossaries-extra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526417/problem-with-chappg-sty-when-using-glossaries-extra-sty)
- `\renewcommand{\theHpage}` changes the `name{page.1-1}` but not much else (I'm probably doing it wrong)
- [This forum post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22504) is almost precisely my case and also mentions `\glsSetCompositor` and I ensured `\makeglossaries` was *after* `\glsSetCompositor` but I still get the warning...

**MWE:**
I've left the options I pass to `glossaries` in the MWE just in case that's useful.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,nopostdot,noredefwarn]{glossaries}

\glsSetCompositor{-}

\makeglossaries%

\newglossaryentry{help}{%
    name={Help},
    description={Heeeeeeelp!}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\chapter{one}
\gls{help}, I need somebody, \gls{help}, not just anybody!
\clearpage
\pagenumbering[GLO]{bychapter}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

(I wanted to add the `chappg` tag but I don't have enough reputation yet)

Comment: at first load hyperref later, with a few exception it should be loaded as the last package.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but the `glossaries` and `chappg` manuals both specifically say to load `hyperref` first...

Comment: I see no reference to hyperref in the chappg manual.

Comment: My apologies, you're right, it's actually the `hyperref` documentation that says to load `chappg` second. https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-620009.1.9

Comment: hm, no idea if this is still valid. Try the order chappg, hyperref, glossaries. (I don't have the time now to think about this).

Comment: Hmm, it seems you're right. Thank you for your time thus far, I've tried this with my MWE and it works for it, but not with my actual code, so there must be some other package causing a similar issue (which I don't grok), I'll try different orders and muddle through.